Socket IO - Websocket connection failed
I am using socket io for my project and I am getting error websocket connection failed.

I am using Express JS as backend and NEXT JS for frontend Below are the code for connections -
Express Server -
require("dotenv").config({ path: "config.env" });
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 777;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL || "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
const connectToMongo = require("./middleware/db");
const { Server } = require("socket.io"); // Import Socket.IO
const http = require("http"); // Required to wrap Express app

connectToMongo();

// Handle uncaught Error
process.on("uncaughtException", (err) => {
  console.log(`Error ${err}`);
  console.log("Shutting down server due to uncaught exception error");
  process.exit(1);
});

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("API Working");
  res.send("API is working");
});

app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "https://kkp-badminton.netlify.app"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});

app.use("/api/match", require("./routes/match"));
app.use("/api/player", require("./routes/player"));
app.use("/api/round", require("./routes/round"));
app.use("/api/tournament", require("./routes/tournament"));

// Create the HTTP server
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Integrate Socket.IO with the HTTP server
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL || "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
  transports: ["websocket", "polling"],
  path: "/socket",
});

// Define Socket.IO events
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New client connected:", socket.id);

  socket.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error("Socket.IO Error:", err);
  });

  // Example: Handle a custom event
  socket.on("getMatch", (payload) => {
    console.log("Received 'getMatch' event with payload:", payload);
    io.emit("getMatch", payload); // Broadcast the event to all connected clients
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected:", socket.id);
  });
});

//Server Listening
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on PORT = ", PORT);
});

//Unhandled Promise Rejection
process.on("unhandledRejection", (err) => {
  console.log(`Error : ${err}`);
  console.log("Shutting Down Server due to unhandle Promise Rejection");

  server.close(() => {
    process.exit(1);
  });
});


Next JS -
"use client";

import { io } from "socket.io-client";

let socket;
const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined";

export const getSocket = () => {
  if (socket) {
    return socket;
  }
  socket = isBrowser
    ? io(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL, {
        path: "/socket",
        transports: ["websocket", "polling"],
        reconnection: true,
        reconnectionAttempts: 5,
      })
    : {};
  return socket;
};

I tried Next JS custom server also on Netlify but because Netlify doesn't support custom server due to its serverless nature, I dropped that idea. I have made separate server on express and hosted on Vercel and then I got this connection error.
